# Connect MySQL database to Glassfish

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish

I'm Trying to connect my JSF project with my local MySQL DB.
In Netbeans everything runs and i can connect to MySQL. But if i try to build my project i become the error: `"GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false ... The module has not been deployed."`

If i try to create a new JDBC Connection Pool and ping that, i become the error: 
Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQL. No password credential found.

Could it be, because my user has no password? How can i add a JDBC Connection Pool with a empty password?

I copied already the the `mysql-connector-java-jar` into `glassfish-4.1\glassfish\lib`.

there are a lot of posts with the same problem but no solution was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, it actually was because my user had no password. With a password it runs.